# How to correctly say "east-north-east"

Tags: word-usage

The four compass directions are: *north*, *south*, *east*, *west*. Can the English language make combinations of these? Something like *south-west* or *east-north-east* to have more options for directions to indicate. And how should these be spelled out - with dashes or space-separated or simply merged?

In my native Danish language we have several versions, all compactly merged with no spacing in-between, for example:

> Sydvest = South-west *(equally much south and west)*
>
> Østnordøst = East-north-east *(both east and north, but more east than north)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We learned the names of the 32 wind directions in the Boy Scouts, but in practice, it is extremely rare ever to see more than the basic eight— *north*, *northeast*, *east*, *southeast*, *south*, *southwest*, *west*, *northwest* — and most people will not know the others unless they have a maritime background. Precise directions are nowadays more usually indicated by numerical degree values.

In older materials you will sometimes see the intermediate directions hyphenated (e.g. *south-east*), but this is uncommon nowadays.

[image: Compass Rose with direction abbreviations, GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.2]

Going clockwise from North, the points are

1. **N** - North
2. **NbE** - North by east
3. **NNE** - North-northeast
4. **NEbN** - Northeast by north
5. **NE** - Northeast
6. **NEbE** - Northeast by east
7. **ENE** - East-northeast
8. **EbM** - East by north
9. **E** - East
10. **EbS** - East by south
11. **ESE** - East-southeast
12. **SEbE** - Southeast by east
13. **SE** - Southeast
14. **SEbS** - Southeast by south
15. **SSE** - South-southeast
16. **SbE** - South by east
17. **S** - South
18. **SbW** - South by west
19. **SSW** - South-southwest
20. **SWbS** - Southwest by south
21. **SW** - Southwest
22. **SWbW** - Southwest by west
23. **WSW** - West-southwest
24. **WbS** - West by south
25. **W** - West
26. **WbN** - West by north
27. **WNW** - West-northwest
28. **NWbW** - Northwest by west
29. **NW** - Northwest
30. **NWbN** - Northwest by north
31. **NNW** - North-northwest
32. **NbW** - North by west

Comment: +1 *All the Quarters that they know, I'th' Ship-mans Card.*

Comment: I was taught 16 directions in geography class at secondary school, so I became familiar with East Southeast, etc. YMMV though.

Comment: Sometimes, especially in Mark Twain, I have seen directions with the word "and" thrown in there. [For instance](https://books.google.com/books?id=rHQBAAAAQAAJ&dq=mark%20twain%20%22and%20by%20nor%22&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q=mark%20twain%20%22and%20by%20nor%22&f=false):

 ' How's she heading? ' / 'Nor'-east-and-by-nor' -- east-by-east, half-east, sir.'

Comment: I always hear the ones like NNW that you labeled with hyphens here said as "North by Northwest" rather than "North-Northwest".  Maybe this is just less formal, or just a regional thing, but Alfred Hitchcock famously named a movie this way.

Comment: And Hitchcock got it from Shakespeare (King Lear). You can't get a much better authority in Englush than that. @DarrenRinger

Comment: @DarrenRinger a certain [festival](https://www.sxsw.com/)

Comment: @user207421 — it was _Hamlet_ that had the eponymous hero claim, “I am but mad north-north-west. When the wind is southerly, I know a hawk from a handsaw.”

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and they are called **[intermediate  (intercardinal or ordinal) directions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction)** and are located halfway between the cardinal directions (*north, east, south, and west*):

- Northeast (NE), 45°, halfway between north and east, is the opposite of southwest.
- Southeast (SE), 135°, halfway between south and east, is the opposite of northwest.
- Southwest (SW), 225°, halfway between south and west, is the opposite of northeast.
- Northwest (NW), 315°, halfway between north and west, is the opposite of southeast.

The intermediate direction of every set of intercardinal and cardinal direction is called a secondary-intercardinal direction, the eight shortest points in the compass rose that is shown to the right—i.e., NNE, ENE, ESE, etc.

[image: 16 point Compass Rose]

This Wikipedia article - "[**Points of the compass**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass)" may be of much interest to you. It lists the **32 cardinal points** and **128 Quarter-Points**, their *traditional wind point*, *azimuths*, and *abbreviations*.

[image: 32 point Compass Rose]

Comment: I wanted to list all the 128 points but thought a person who's really interested can click the link and read the article.